# Latex Table for Dynamically generated table and traceback arrows

Tags: tables, arrows, matrices, tikz-arrows

I am trying to fill in a table generated by a dynamic programming algorithm which requires to keep trace of the execution by inserting right or diagonally downwards arrow. An example image is below:

[image]

I know the command for table and arrows but can't get this done compactly. 
What would be the basic table structure so that this alignment is visible?

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{||c c c c c c c c||} 
        \hline
        Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 & Col1 & Col2 & Col2 & Col3 \\ [0.5ex] 
        \hline\hline
        1 & 6 & 10 & 87837 \\ 

        $\leftarrow$ & $\leftarrow$ & $\searrow$ & 87837 \\ 

        2 & 7 & 78 & 5415 \\

        3 & 545 & 778 & 7507 \\

        4 & 545 & 18744 & 7560 \\

        5 & 88 & 788 & 6344 \\ [1ex] 

    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

This code gives me a structure like this:
[image]
As you can see, it's not quite ok. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should show the effort you already put into your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use for this purpose `tikz` with `matrix` library. 
In this case you can draw arrows simply from cell to another with

```
\draw[->](A-n-p)--(A-m-q);
```

where `A` is the name of matrix,  `n` and `P` represent row number and column number of starting cell.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=stealth]
\matrix (A) [matrix of nodes,row sep=3mm,column sep=3mm,nodes in empty cells]
{
  & A   & T     & T     & A    \\
G & 1   & 6     & 10    & 87837\\
A & 3   & 5     & 7     & 87837\\
T & 7   & 78    & 5415  & 10   \\
G & 545 & 778   & 7507  & 20   \\
T & 545 & 18744 & 7560  & 19   \\
A & 88  & 788   & 6344  & 50   \\
};
\draw (A-7-1.south west)rectangle({A-2-5.north east}|-{A-1-2.north});
\draw ([xshift=-3mm]A-1-2.north west)--([xshift=-3mm]A-7-2.south west);
\draw ([yshift=2mm]A-2-1.north west)--([yshift=2mm]A-2-5.north east);
\begin{scope}[thick,red,->]
\draw (A-2-2)--(A-3-3);
\draw (A-2-2)--(A-2-3);
\draw (A-2-2)--(A-3-2);
\draw (A-3-4)--(A-4-4);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]