# I am trying to build the following dynamic programming table in LaTeX. How would I do this?

Tags: tables, algorithms

[image: LCS problem Table]

How would I go about building something like this? I have no clue.

Comment: What aspect of the table do you find difficult? What have you tried so far?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/276052/latex-table-for-dynamically-generated-table-and-traceback-arrows